# Jest test suites fail when executed in parallel but succeed when run individually

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I'm using JestJS for end-to-end testing of my NestJS API

When I run all end-to-end tests (which are split up across many files, each file contains one test suite):

'npm run test:e2e'

Multiple tests are filing (different ones everytime).

When I run each test suite individually, the tests pass 100% of the time.

Here's one of my test files:

```
describe('Cameras - /components/cameras (e2e)', () => {
const camerasRequest = {
  CameraSerialNumber: 1,
  Status: "online",
};

const camerasResponse = {
  CameraSerialNumber: 1,
  Status: "online",
};

let app: INestApplication;

beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [
          TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
            type: 'mysql',
            host: 'localhost',
            username: 'root',
            password: 'pass',
            database: 'test',
            autoLoadEntities: true,
            synchronize: false,
          }),
          CamerasModule,
        ],
        providers: [{
            provide: APP_FILTER,
            useClass: GlobalExceptionFilter,
        }],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
});

describe("Response code: 200", () => {
  it('Delete one camera [DELETE /components/cameras/:id]', async () => {
    await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/components/cameras')
      .send(camerasRequest as CreateCameraDto)

    await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .delete('/components/cameras/1')
      .expect(200)
      .then(({ body }) => {
        expect(body.affected).toStrictEqual(1);
      });

    await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/components/cameras/1')
      .expect(200)
      .then(({ body }) => {
        expect(body).toStrictEqual({});
      });

    return
  });

  it('Delete one camera with unknown camera serial number [DELETE /components/cameras/:id]', async () => {
    await request(app.getHttpServer())
        .delete('/components/cameras/99')
        .expect(200)
        .then(({ body }) => {
          expect(body.affected).toStrictEqual(0)
        });

    return
  });
});

describe("Response code: 400", () => {
});

afterEach( async () => {
    await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .delete('/components/cameras/1');

    await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .delete('/components/cameras/2');
    return;
})
```

});

My guess is that the problem lies within the way Jest parallelizes the execution of my test suites... I can't find a fix for this. What can I do?

Comment: What's the error? And do you want to let them run in parallel or just one at a time?

Comment: There is no error, it is only that certain tests fail when I run all e2e tests at once, but that no tests fail when I run each test suite one by one. I would like to let them run just one at a time, as I think that will fix the error, but I am not sure how